# How to diable job start after rebase in gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

Good day, I have this rules on my gitlab-task

```
workflow:

   rules:

- if: '$CUSTOM_ENV'
- if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
  when: never
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
- when: always
```

...

```
 myTask:

  stage: build

  script:
    - "SOME SCRIPT"

  rules:

- if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
- if: '$CUSTOM_ENV'
  when: manual
```

...

myTask run in all merge_request_event. How create "if" which doens't run myTask after (rebase + push)?

Comment: You mean after merging to the default branch?

Comment: no, before merge i press 'rebase' button in gitlab interface. Afrer that new pipline created and myTask job was run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @sytech, it's work, but not resolve my problem.
Сolleagues suggested a workaround to me:

Before i press "Rebase" button in Gitlab interface, i can set special label (i.e. skip-myTask) for my MR. It's work in one click. And after that i add new rule for myTask.

```
- if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS =~ /.*skip-myTask.*/'
      when: manual
- if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
- if: '$CUSTOM_ENV'
      when: manual
```

Important to save this order, otherwise myTask will running.

Sorry for the not quite accurate question!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in particular that distinguishes a rebase and push from any other push event.

You could, however, supply [git push options](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html#push-options-for-gitlab-cicd) for this:

```
git push -o ci.variable="SKIP_MY_TASK=true"
```

Then in your yaml:

```yaml
- if: '$SKIP_MY_TASK && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
  when: never
```

If you rebase from the UI, you could perhaps set this variable in the CI/CD settings, then unset it afterwards.

[Reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines)